# Bootstrap 4 dropdown button not working in mvc view

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am working with asp.net mvc. I need to add dropdown button in a view but it is not working. I include the library also.

```
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Location
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu3" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Sort By
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu3">
                <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Action</button>
                <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Another action</button>
                <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Something else here</button>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

I also added this.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.slim.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The html is just fine . its working . Just make sure you are pointing to right folder structure for both css and js files . There is nothing specific to MVC for it not to work other than css and js files not loading

Comment: I check all the required files. Those are fine. But i don't understand why dropdown not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Order of the reference is important in this case

The Sequence of reference must be as follows:

```
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="~/Scripts/popper.js"></script>
 <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Scripts must be referred before CSS

Comment: CSS files can be placed before scripts as well.

Comment: You were right. I was not following the order that's why it was not working. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the BundleConfig.cs file, change ~/bundles/bootstrap to use the bootstrap.bundle.min, as this includes references to popper utils:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.bundle.min.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));
```